# Two questions regarding Lebesgue measure and integral

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I have these two homework problems and both seem intuitively wrong and I really cannot find anyway to prove them.
1) For $f \in L^1(m)$ show $m({x: f(x) = \infty}) = 0$, ($ f $ maps to $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$) How is this possible at all? Could you not define some measurable function $f$ that maps to infinity at all but some uncountable subset of $\mathbb{R}$

2. The second question seems even more off base. For $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n, m) $, define $f^{\sigma}(v_1,..., v_r) = f(\sigma_1*v_1,..., \sigma_r*v_r)$. Show $f^{\sigma}$ is Lebesgue integrable and further that $\int f^{sigma} = \frac{1}{\sigma_1}*...*\frac{1}{\sigma_r}\int f$. Shouldn't it not be the reciprocal?

Comment: If $f\in L^1$, then $\infty>\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f|=\int_{\{|f|<\infty\}}|f|+\int_{\{|f|=\infty\}}\leq\int_{\{|f|=\infty\}}=\infty\cdot m(\{|f|=\infty\})$. Therefore, $m(\{|f|=\infty\})=0$.

Comment: The second part is just an application of the change of variable. If you can't just invoke it, you can prove it directly by starting from simple functions. Use that Lebesgue measure scales with multiplication.

Comment: @totoro shouldn't it be $\int f^{\sigma} = \sigma_1*...*\sigma_r\int f$?

Comment: Nop. The way it is now is correct: $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(rx)dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(y)d\left(\frac{y}{r}\right)=\frac{1}{r}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(y)dy$

Comment: @totoro Oh I get it now I have no idea why I made that mistake. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If $f$ maps into $\bar{\Bbb R}$, it could be even defined constantly $\infty$. However, being in $L^1(m) $ means that $\int\lvert f\rvert\, dm<\infty$. 
   Let $A:=f^{-1}(\infty)$. Then we have
   $$\int_A \lvert f\rvert\, dm\le\int\lvert f\rvert\, dm$$
2. You can check it for one variable first,   recall from calculus that if $F'(x) =f(x) $ then $[F(cx)]'=c\cdot F'(cx)=c\cdot f(cx) $ so that
   $$F(cx) =c\cdot\int f(cx) \, dx$$

Comment: So then shouldn't it be $ \int f^{\sigma} = \sigma_1*...\sigma_r \int f$?

Comment: No: we get $\int f(\sigma x) \, dx=\frac 1\sigma\int f(x) \, dx$. Apply this to each variable.

Answer (score 0):

Let $E_n=(|f|>n)$ for $n\ge1$. Then
$$
\lVert f\rVert_1\ge\int_{E_n}|f|\,d\mu\geq m(E_n)n
$$
whence
$$
m(E_n)\leq n^{-1}\lVert f\rVert_1<\infty$$
Let $n\to \infty$. So
$$
0=\lim_{n\to\infty}m(E_n)=m(\cap_n E_n)=m(|f|=\infty)
$$
by measure continuity from above.